# How to make a fetch request everytime a prop changes in a component in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

Script part of a simple component, this component receives an `id` from its parent which triggers a fetch request based on that id. Problem here is that the component only mounts once and therefore, whenever a new prop is passed, there is no change. What is the best way to handle this situation?

```
  import request from "@src/modules/request"; //not important, performs a GET request
  export let channelId;
  let streams = [];

  onMount(async()=>{
    const response = await request({
      url: `/streams?channel_id=${channelId}`,
    });
    streams = response.streams;
  })
```

What I tried: using `beforeUpdate` but that resulted in multiple calls which was unncessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a reactive declaration, like:

```
  $: {
    const response = await request({
      url: `/streams?channel_id=${channelId}`,
    });

    streams = response.streams;
  }
```

Comment: sorry but this does not seem to work, even after putting in an async function

Comment: ah my bad, didnt invoke the functional afterwards, seems to be working now, thanks!